# Converting it to using Guzzle doesn't work

Tags: php, http, fopen, guzzle

I have the following code that is currently used on an SDK for an integration and I want to migrate this to using Guzzle PHP for a cleaner and simplified code.

```php
<?php

class Request
{
    private $is_last_session_id;

    public function send($s_url, $data)
    {

        $params = [
            'http' => [
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $data,
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ],
        ];

        $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

        ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP Client /5.2.00');

        $fp = fopen($s_url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

        $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

        $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

        foreach (array_keys($meta) as $h) {
            $v = $meta[$h];
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach (array_keys($v) as $hh) {
                    $vv = $v[$hh];
                    if (is_string($vv) && substr_count($vv, 'JSESSIONID')) {
                        $this->is_last_session_id = substr($vv, strpos($vv, '=') + 1, 24);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that uses Guzzle

```php
    private function guzzleRequest($uri, $data)
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $client->request('POST', $uri, [
            'form_params' => $data,
            'headers'     => [
                'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

From the code, I understand that it is doing a POST request, but when I try to use Guzzle's `$client->post()` or `$client->request('POST',$data)` with the specific headers as per the code above, I get a 500 server error. The above code as is works fine. Am I missing something when calling the methods using Guzzle?

Comment: Need to see your Guzzle code....

Comment: @gview added the guzzle code

Comment: Also please post your exception error. Which version of Guzzle are you using? You don't need that content-type header, the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is set by default when POSTing the `form_params`

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->request('POST', $uri, ['form_params' => $data]);
```